# Do context switches take up memory?

Tags: linux, process, memory, resources

I’m relatively new to Linux, and I had a few questions about context switching. What kind of system resources does a context switch take up? Does it take up memory? If so, will the memory show up as belonging to the process that is switching? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel uses a small amount of memory to store information about each task in the system, and some of that information is used to perform context switches. But each individual context switch doesn’t take any additional memory.

The only resources consumed by context switches are time and energy.

Comment: Thank you! When you say time, do you mean cpu time?

Comment: Yes, CPU time, and real-world time.